# How to create visualization from splunk stats in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, statistics, visualization, splunk

I'm working on creating a slackbot that would talk to Splunk and get the trends/stats in visualization format.
I'm looking for some documentation/relevant links to understand how can we create a visualization from Splunk stats using Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first you could save your splunk results to a csv-file. Afterwards you could make the visualization with [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/).